# Swap is half full but nothing is going in or out of swap

Tags: memory, kill, swap

I ran a job that exceeded the memory, and began to write into the swap. The swap is 25 GB, and the RAM is 1TB.

I have stopped the job when the swap was full until 11GB, so 50% of it was still empty.

It did not trigger any OOM kill jobs, so everything is going as normal as before it happened.

I have only 8GB swap used now (3GB is cleaned after I have stopped the job), and it is slowly decreasing. But when I check `vmstat`, the `si` and `so` are both `0`, so there is nothing going in or out of swap? How can this be possible?

```
free -lm
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1031757      475637       49100          63      507019      553720
Low:        1031757      982657       49100
High:             0           0           0
Swap:         25767        8272       17495
```

I have a free space of `40GB` in `RAM`, so should I expect that my running jobs will be killed by `OOM` not now but later on? `8GB` used in `swap` is smaller than `40GB` free space in `RAM`, so it looks fine, but I am not sure if still tells that `OOM` won't be triggered..

Couple months ago, when the `OOM` was triggered, it killed all my jobs and used swap was `25GB` (all full) and then 10 minutes later `0GB`. 
However in this case, it takes a day to clean `2-3 GB` from `swap.`
Is it bad news for my running jobs?

Do you think my running jobs are in danger of being killed, not now but later on, when free swapspace reaches `0 GB` as it would trigger `OOM` to kill?
If that is the case, how can I prevent it from happening?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you seem to have created a duplicate account.   to fix, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Are you running vmstat with a count/delay?

Comment: I am not sure. I am just asking for vmstat without any parameters

Answer (score 1):

`vmstat` without parameters shows the average values since reboot. As the swap in / swap out is shown as blocks/second, it's not strange that those are showing 0, if you have a reasonable uptime.

Whatever is now in swap is memory that is in use, but not used since the time it was swapped out due to the overloading of the memory by your process. This is actually a good thing, as many processes have memory that is e.g. only used during startup. Having this swapped out means that you have more free RAM available for processes and buffers/cache.

The reason that in the earlier case, when you *did* get OOM, afterwards all swapspace was free again shortly after the event is probably because the OOM-causing process had used all the space and after it was stopped all the swapspace was free again.

The only time when you will get OOM is when there is no free swap space, and there is no RAM free (taking into account the buffers/cache, i.e. the "available" column of the `free` command).

For the rest you can usually trust Linux's memory management to do the right thing. Only if you have really special requirements due to the sort of load / application you're running can it be necessary to start tuning the memory management.

Comment: I mean when swap reaches 0GB in use space ( so it will be all free )

Comment: OK, I've edited your question a bit to make it a bit clearer. And edited my answer to explain the free swap in the OOM case.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. However, if I got into the swap directly, wouldnt some jobs be flagged to be killed by OMM already? So that I will have a problem when the swap is all free?

Comment: Only if there is no free memory and no free swap will the OOM killer be invoked. Jobs aren't "flagged" to be killed, the OOM killer, when started, looks for the best candidate to kill, which is usually the job that has caused the OOM condition.

Comment: I understand..Thank you very much for your informative replies. They helped me a lot.